# Using MSER as a keypoint detector and SIFT as descriptor

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract keypoints using MSER and use SIFT as a feature descriptor, and then match the matching keypoints. I did the following using Python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg') 

mser = cv2.MSER_create()

kp1 = mser.detect(img1)
kp2 = mser.detect(img2)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, kp1)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, kp2)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.8 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

good = sorted(good, key=lambda x: x.distance)
print len(good)

matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags=2)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', matching_result)
```

But, get the following error:

```
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, kp1)
TypeError: mask is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

How can I fix this issue? And, is it right the way I'm using the detector and descriptor?

Comment: instead of `detectAndCompute` is there a `compute` method in python api? That one shoud be used if you want to input precomputed keypoints to describe them.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the descriptors based on the existing keypoints. A quick fix could be change these lines from your code:

```
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, kp1)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, kp2)
```

Instead, using the compute() function:

```
kp1, des1 = sift.compute(img1, kp1)
kp2, des2 = sift.compute(img2, kp2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. What I meant in my question is that I want to use MSER as a feature "detector", and SIFT as a feature "descriptor". So, I need to use both. Hope this clarifies the point?